# my ionic app turned to a black background on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, browser, background

I built my app, using the default "ionic start" command. I chose "blank" app and if I test on browser, background is white, but if I test the same blank app, on my android phone using "ionic cordova run android" the app background is black. Why?

Comment: maybe your phone is in dark mode or you haven't handled that?

Comment: Try debugging the app and check how the black background is applied. [How to debug android apps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android#debugging-android-apps)

Answer (score 5):

Latest ionic update has theme related conflicts in latest android versions (not  sure).
My solution-

1. Open **theme/variables.scss** inside your project.
2. Search for **"dark"** and you will find something like **@media..dark**..
3. **Comment out the whole block related to dark**.
4. Open **index.html**  and **search 'light dark'**. **Remove the 'dark'** and rebuild the app.
5. Now your **app uses correct colors**.

Comment: This seems to work for me except the first time the app is launched, which still has dark mode....

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this.

1. Open **theme/variable.scss**
2. Search **@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)** and replace by **@media (prefers-color-scheme: primary)**